# can we use other objects rather than id while dynamic routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

I'm trying to fetch the Reddit post detail page and the post detail page details are in the permalink and when I define permalink rather than id it goes blank.

Here are the code snippets

The first code is for the photos grid page and the second code snippet is the photo detail page.

API reference link: https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper.json

First Page

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from "react"
import '../App.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Chips, Chip } from '@mantine/core';
import { LazyLoadImage } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import 'react-lazy-load-image-component/src/effects/blur.css';

const PAGE_NUMBER =1;

export const SimpleInfiniteList = () => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);
  const [img, setImg] = useState('')
  const [page, setPage] = useState(PAGE_NUMBER)
  const iddata = img.slice(-1)
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('')

 const baseUrl = 'https://www.reddit.com/r'
 const subreddit = 'wallpaper'


  const filtered = (e) => {
    setFilter(e)
    
  }

  useEffect ( async() => {
    await fetch(`${baseUrl}/${subreddit}/${filter}.json?after=${ iddata.length > 0 ? iddata.map(id => `t3_${id.data.id}`): ''}&page=${page}&limit=25`)
    .then(response =>  response.json())
    .then(data => setImg(currentImage =>  ([...currentImage,...data.data.children]))
    )

  },[page])



  useEffect( () => {
  fetch(`${baseUrl}/${subreddit}/${filter}.json?after=${ iddata.length > 0 ? iddata.map(id => `t3_${id.data.id}`): ''}&page=${page}&limit=5`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setImg([ ...data.data.children], 
    )
  )
}, [filter])

console.log(img)


const scrollToEnd = () => {
  setPage(page + 1) 
}
window.onscroll = function () {
  const bottom =  Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight
  
  if (bottom,
     Math.ceil(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight
    ) {
      scrollToEnd() 
      console.log('loading....')
  }
}



  return (
    <>



    <div className='App'>

    

     

    <div className="filters">
<Chips>
  <Chip value="new" onClick={(e) => filtered(e.target.value)}>New</Chip>
  <Chip value="best" onClick = {(e) => filtered(e.target.value)}>Top</Chip>
  <Chip value="rising" onClick = { (e) => filtered(e.target.value)}>Rising</Chip>
  <Chip value="hot" onClick = {(e) => filtered(e.target.value)}>Random</Chip>
  <Chip onClick={() => setOpened(true)}>Random</Chip>
  
</Chips>
</div>
    {img.length > 1 &&
    
      img.filter(imgs => imgs.data.post_hint==='image').map(imgs => (
       <>

{console.log(imgs.data.url_overridden_by_dest)}
        <div className='image'>
         {`/item/${imgs.data.permalink.substring(1)}`}
        <Link to={`/item/${imgs.data.permalink.substring(1)}`} >
        <LazyLoadImage src={imgs.data.url_overridden_by_dest} effect="blur" delayMethod='debounce' threshold='100'  >

           
          </LazyLoadImage  >
          </Link>
         </div>
        

         <p >{imgs.data.title} </p>
         <p className='title'>{imgs.data.author}</p>
         <p className='description'> {imgs.data.subreddit}</p>
          </>    
      )
      )
    }    
</div>

    </>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Detail page

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'


export const PhotoDetails = () => {

    const {permalink} = useParams()
    console.log(permalink)
    

    return (
        
        <div>
    

            <p>{permalink}</p>
            
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What goes blank? You'll have to provide a [mcve] for us to understand your issue properly.

Comment: @Andy I console the permalink in my detail page, nothing print in console with permalink

Comment: @Andy  <Link to={`/item/${imgs.data.permalink.substring(1)}`} > and my detail page const {permalink} = useParams()
    console.log(permalink)

Comment: Sudo, this is a site that helps diagnose issues with code. And we can't do that if we can't see your code. You've tagged `react`. Could you add that code to your question using the snippet tool `[<>]` in the edit menu bar?

Comment: @Andy code added